# htaccess rewrite all pages to same rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have added a rewrite rule in htaccess file and it is working fine the only problem is if I open any URL from after 2016 directory it opens the same target file.

```
RewriteRule ^elections/assembly/2016/(.*)$ elections/assembly/2016/index.php?state=$1
```

For example :-

http://www.example.com/elections/assembly/2016/dir1/dir2/index.php

the above URL follow the same pattern. 
please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to exclude your real files and dirs from the rule :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^elections/assembly/2016/(.*)$ elections/assembly/2016/index.php?state=$1
```

Comment: can you please help me to understand what is the meaning of !-d and !-f

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` is a condition to the rule, it says if the request is not for an existent dir, the rewrite the request otherwise skip the rewrite. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` works the same way but it handles existent files.